# What is the best Web interface to bind9 for a small ISP?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-applications, isp, bind

I am looking for a Web interface to bind9, to edit zones, add records, etc, with user access privileges (not Webmin please!) but free and possibly open-source.
I have googled a lot, but I only found stalled projects, or very old ones, not updated after 2002 or so.

It would be great a nice Web2.0 UI, but at this point it's not crucial.

Thanks a lot!
Gabble

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [unxsBind](http://openisp.net/openisp/unxsVZ)  is somewhat what you're looking for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While I realize that it can be a little daunting getting started, I highly suggest getting comfortable with a text editor if you're going to manage a bind server. Being able to easily modify text files is part of what makes bind useful.

Just so you have a little background, I currently run a little over 1400 domains (all owned by us, not co-hosting) on a hidden master plus two clusters of "main" servers. Correct configuration of rndc is a must, as are a few shell scripts that help with the actual configuration files (for adding/removing domains).

Comment: I already manage several bind9 servers by command line and text editors. I was looking for a Web front-end for customers, that was easy to use, customizable, with user access privileges.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the impression from your OP that you were already familiar with using bind from the CLI. As to your question, I've not used the product, but have known several other admins that spoke highly of ISPConfig: http://www.ispconfig.org/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't suggest one because I've never found a good one.  Try searching for "open source control panel", you'll get a few possible suggestions.  While most are for LAMP hosting setups, they will also include a DNS component.  You'll find most are limiting though.  Most DNS administrators go with a home grown solution or a commercial product such as [Men and Mice](http://www.menandmice.com/solutions/).